# Console prints not appearing when using Docker in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, docker, printf

I've been trying to use Docker for development, it works pretty well but one of the things that annoys me is not being able to see the console prints.

Rails server (exactly the same application):

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 22:18:28 +0200
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
foobar
Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/home (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 19.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Docker:

```
Started GET "/" for 192.168.99.1 at 2015-10-14 20:18:44 +0000
Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/home (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 179ms (Views: 177.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

These logs are from tailing the log/development.log file within my container.

Has anyone else encountered this before? How to solve this? Cheers!

Comment: Maybe this would help? http://serverfault.com/a/634296/783

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that this isn't something Docker related by tailing a non-Docker project. Logging tools like `puts` or `print` are displayed in your console when using WEBrick, but aren't added to your log files.

The solution to this is by using `logger.info()` instead.